# How do I report landing on an illegal proxy site without having to create a Google account?

Tags: support, copycat-sites

Just now I landed on a page entitled

> You have landed on a site that is proxying a site in the Stack Exchange network

with instructions on how to report this to Google. However I don't have a Google account and am not inclined to create one.

For obvious reasons I was asked not to post any details publicly.

I have noted the search query that got me there, which I can pass along to an authorized requester.

**Update**:

I was referring to the new *malware* page that just went up recently, as *@animuson* noted below. However I have sent details to the **Contact Us** email as *@animuson* suggested.

Comment: @Makoto Not the same thing. He's talking about the new [malware page](http://stackexchange.com/about/malware) which just went up recently. These sites are already handled and being actively blocked, so reporting them to *us* won't really achieve anything.

Comment: @animuson: However, I have just sent an email with details to the Contact email as Makoto suggested. At least I have done my bit, I believe

Comment: @animuson:  Okay.  I hadn't known about that form.

Comment: Sorry, can anyone explain to me what's happening here with that proxying thing?

Comment: @user2875404: i guess that, by proxying, you can acquire users credentials

Comment: _"However I don't have a Google account and am not inclined to create one."_ Why not? It's not like Google doesn't know anything about you.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Clearly there is something, at least, that Google would like to know further. To create an account I must make at least two decisions that Google currently has limited knowledge about - the username preference I expose, and the password selection process I expose (leet-speak, horse battery, with or without spaces). Further, this is now an additional account that I must manage in some way going forward. I decline to do that in order to accede to their request for assistance.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Hm, I didn't consider the password selection process. Thanks for the reply.